# Issues with the scripting REST API of Sonatype Nexus 3.0-M7

Tags: api, nexus, sonatype

I'm trying to automate the deployment of a Nexus 3.0-M7 instance (installation and configuration) and I can't manage to make the scripting API work, even when following the official tutorial: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html

When I invoke the API, all I receive is 404 error with no content.

Is there something I'm missing? I suspect the API not to be available in this release but I found nothing about that on the Internet...

Cheers,

Radium.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicions are correct, the API isn't in 3.0m7, it's in the soon to be released 3.0 version of Nexus.